# Why is the Gradle Versions Plugin not seeing the latest version of some dependencies?

Tags: gradle

When using the [Gradle Versions Plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin), sometimes it reports:

```
The following dependencies exceed the version found at the release revision level
```

or

```
The following dependencies exceed the version found at the milestone revision level
```

when the dependency versions I am using are the latest released versions, and so this should never happen. It seems like it's only seeing up the the previous version of these dependencies.

How can I force it to see their latest versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle has a local cache. You can force it to refresh information from the remote repositories using the `--refresh-dependencies` flag. eg:

```
./gradlew --refresh-dependencies dependencyUpdates -Drevision=release
```

Comment: Also, if you have multiple Gradle daemons, you should stop them and then refresh dependencies

Comment: Also, other possible values for `-Drevision` flag are described at https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin#revisions